# How do I get a list of numbers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a database of movies, and I'd like a list of years where I don't have a movie for that year. So all I need is a list (1900 .. 2012) and then I can JOIN and IN and NOT IN on that all I want.

I've got:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE build_years(p1 SMALLINT) 
BEGIN 
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE year (year SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED); 
    label1: LOOP 
        INSERT INTO year VALUES (p1); 
        SET p1 = p1 + 1; 
        IF p1 > 2012 THEN LEAVE label1; END IF; 
    END LOOP; 
END
```

But that seems so unSQL and only marginally less kludgy then running Python code to create the same table. I'd really like something that didn't use a stored procedure, didn't use looping and didn't use an actual table, in that order of concern.

Comment: Why do you not want to use an actual table? Seems like it would be useful if you are going to run this query more than once?

Comment: I was really hoping there was some direct code I had overlooked that I could use inline for general purposes. It just feels like everytime I create a new temporary table in SQL, I've missed the elegant solution. Especially here where I'm creating a permanent table to replace Python's range(1900, 2013).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had similar problem a few years ago. My solution was:

**1. Sequence table**

I created a table filled with integer sequence from 0 to < as much as it will be required >:

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (n INT);
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4);
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+5 FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+10 FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+20 FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+40 FROM numbers;
etc.
```

It is executed only once, so can be created from outside of your app, even by hand.

**2. Select data of a needed type and range**

For integers it is obvious - i.e. range 1..99:

```
SELECT n FROM numbers WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 99;
```

Dates - 2h intervals from now to +2 days:

```
SELECT date_add(now(),INTERVAL 2*n HOUR) FROM numbers WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND 23;
```

So in your case it could be:

```
SELECT n+1900 AS n_year FROM numbers WHERE n BETWEEN 0 AND 112;
```

Then `JOIN` it on `n_year`.

Comment: This answer isn't necessarily exactly what I was requesting, but I does seem to be the cleanest, most practical and useful solution to the problem. Thanks also to the other people who responded with answers that fulfilled the requirements, even if I found them less practical.

Answer (score 4):

This should work until you need more than 195 years , at which point you'll need to add a `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT Year 
FROM   (   SELECT @i:= @i + 1 AS YEAR
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY,
                  ( SELECT @i:= 1899) AS i
        ) As Y
WHERE   Year BETWEEN 1900 AND 2012
ORDER BY Year;
```

Although I am assuming that the `COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` System table has a default size of 195 based on my trusty testing ground [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b815/1)

Answer (score 1):

This will return a list of 2012 to 1900 if you really want to keep it to a query..

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), ((rno - 1) * -12)), 'YYYY') AS "years"
FROM 
    (
    SELECT 
        LEVEL rno
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
                   (SELECT TO_CHAR (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'YYYY')
                           - 1899
                               yearstobuild
                      FROM DUAL))
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if the the question was tagged with `oracle` and not `MySQL`.

Comment: Argh disaster - completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can think of according to your wishes sucks also ...

```
SELECT years.year FROM
    (
        SELECT 1900 AS year
        UNION SELECT 1901
        ...
        UNION SELECT 2012
    ) AS years
    LEFT OUTER JOIN yourmovietable USING (year)
WHERE yourmovietable.year IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this generic query is faster:

```
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
```

Each query execution duplicates:

```
INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4);

INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
INSERT INTO numbers SELECT n+(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM numbers) FROM numbers;
```

...

Answer (score -1):

```
select year into temporary table blaa from (generate_series(1900,2000)) where year not in(select distinct(year) from films)
```

dont know if this will work  but you get the drift.

Comment: He's not asking how to query his films table (I assume he already knows how to do that). He's asking how to create the year table in a cleaner way. Your query won't work because there won't be any rows with `c = 0`.

Comment: and you can do "create table as"

Comment: good point that it wont work. Then you would have to maybe use a function like generate_series in postgresql to generate a series of years.

Comment: Yes, something like `generate_series` would be useful here. Unfortunately MySQL has no such function. :-(